# Desabilitar button em react através de validação

Tags: javascript, react, regex

Olá, boa noite amigos, tudo bom? Estou tendo problema com a validação de um button, ele deveria ficar desabilitado caso a validação não passasse, porém como sou estudante ainda, não sei dizer ao certo onde estou errado, pois a validação não funciona, alguém poderia me dar uma luz por gentileza?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const minPwdLength = 6;
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
  };
  if (isLoggedIn) return <Redirect to="/carteira" />;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
      <label htmlFor="email">
        Email:
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          placeholder="Digite o seu email"
          data-testid="email-input"
          value={ email }
          onChange={ (e) => setEmail(e.target.value) }
        />
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="password">
        Senha:
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          id="password "
          placeholder="Digite a sua senha"
          data-testid="password-input"
          value={ password }
          onChange={ (e) => setPassword(e.target.value) }
        />
      </label>
      <button
        type="submit"
        disabled={
          !email.match(
            /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/,
          ) && !password.length >= minPwdLength
        }
      >
        Entrar
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, fiz uma pequena alteração em seu código.

Adicionei a `regex` de email antes da `function`

Segue o código da regex

```
let REGEX_EMAIL = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

E no `disabled` da so se `button` fiz a seguite validação

Segue o código da validação

```
disabled={!REGEX_EMAIL.test(email) || password.length <= minPwdLength}
```

Neste código de disable ele faz o teste do email na `regex` e retorna `true` ou `false` e a do password é similar ao seu.

Espero ter ajudado